# Accessing JSON data from Parse with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, parse-platform

I have some files up on Parse.com and want to pull them down using JSON. After I pull down the json data I wish to display this on a HTML page. One of the elements I am pulling down is nested and contains the objectID of a element I wish to make a further call to.

Here is the line I am stuck with:

```
        document.getElementById("subjectName").innerHTML=subject.exam.objectId;
```

This is setting a HTML tag to undefined. If I have a similar structure such as:

```
        document.getElementById("subjectName").innerHTML=subject.exam.className;
```

it will set the element as expected. 
The JSON data I am pulling down is as follows

```
{
"exam": {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "exam",
    "objectId": "UP7CeBZNz8"
},
"name": "Computer Architecture",
"objectId": "Pf1tKLYzjz",
"createdAt": "2014-04-24T09:22:22.732Z",
"updatedAt": "2014-04-29T16:21:40.855Z"
}
```

If anyone can help with this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're setting both to `document.getElementById("subjectName")`. Is that expected?

Comment: What do you see logged if you add `console.log(subject)` at that point in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be because you're setting it to the same element.

if you have used

```
document.getElementById("subjectName").innerHTML
```

in both the assignments, it will not work.
this works:

```
document.getElementById("objectId").innerHTML=subject.exam.objectId;
document.getElementById("subjectName").innerHTML=subject.exam.className;
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7aSTp/)

Comment: That was not the issue. The element was under subject.exam.id rather than .objectId; I dont know why the JSON printout I have used objectId but it is working now :)